# PHP imagejpeg() displays weird characters

Tags: php

**The problem:**

I found this simple script explaining how to use imagejpeg():

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

When I copy/paste it in an empty php file it works just fine. I displays an image.

Now when I insert this code into one of my existing php file formated as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0   Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

***code above***

</body>
</html>
```

It does not return any image. Just lines of weird characters.

**What I think happens:**

I read other posts and I think the problem comes from my main header 'Content-Type'. But I don't understand why the 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' in the embeded code does not supersede whatever is written in the main header? It should tell imagejpeg() to display an image, not text...

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it this way.

```
<?php

    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20);
    $text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
    imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);

    ob_start ();

    imagejpeg($im);
    imagedestroy($im);

    $data = ob_get_contents ();

    ob_end_clean ();

    $image = "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode ($data)."'>";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0   Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo $image; ?> 

</body>
</html>
```

works for me.

Comment: `imagejpeg` probably won't return image data as PNG, though. And for larger images (JPEGs are often a few hundred KiB) I'd say that data URIs are not the best option to use.

Comment: ops! let me mod that.. thanks.. btw.. I have this on a captcha class running.. works wonders in png/jpeg.. but I always pref png :)

Answer (score 3):

This is because it returns the *image data* as if you were including the image file as text. For displaying an image in HTML there is the `img` element:

```
<img src="myimage.php" alt="Pretty, isn't it?">
```

You should also get a warning that headers cannot be modified because they are already sent, which should tip you off that what you're doing is ... strange at best.

Put the code to return the image in a separate PHP file or otherwise make sure that on invocation you either get a HTML page *or* a JPEG image back. Mixing those two isn't that good an idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I was using this method but I thought there was a way to do differently... Using php functions for example.

Comment: ...What I don't really like with the method suggested is that it becomes rapidly inelegant when you want to pass variables. Say you want to indicate width, quality, path of image you have to do it via GET_ variables, right? So it will look something like that: <img src="myimage.php?width=500&quality=80&path=picfolder"> So heavy... It would have been much nicer to just call a php function. Very sad it can't be done...

Comment: Well, you can use other methods for that, e.g. referencing a picture as `/picfolder/500/80/foo.jpg` and using a 404 error handler to create the image and serve it if it doesn't exist. We used that method to get nicer URLs and auto-generate cached images in a browser game years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line before calling **imagejpeg()**

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

That tells the browser that you are displaying an image not HTML.

Comment: sorry, I was having the same problem but for another reason so I thought you were having the same problem I didn't realize this until I submitted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply embed the PHP code in your HTML document and emit the image - the browser is expecting HTML, not image data. The content-type header you emit from your PHP script isn't actually sent since by the time that part of the script is reached the headers have already been sent. Your new header is just discarded, and a warning added to your server log.

To make this work include an HTML image tag in your HTML document, and use your PHP script as its `src` attribute:

```
<body>
  <img src="myPHPScript.php">
</body>
```

You can apply whatever additional styling you need to it, as you would with any other image.